# setenforce: SELinux is disabled

Tags: linux, centos, ftp, selinux

I'm in a CentOS 5 machine, and try to install vsftpd. I want to configure `ftp_home_dir` using `setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on` but it says:

`setsebool:  SELinux is disabled.`

I try to enable it using `setenforce` it still says:

`setenforce: SELinux is disabled`

then I tried:

`semodule -n -B`

and it says:

`semodule: SELinux policy is not managed or store cannot be accessed.`

my **config** file:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - SELinux is fully disabled.
SELINUX=permissive
# SELINUXTYPE= type of policy in use. Possible values are:
#       targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#       strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

**Note:** rebooted many times.

Comment: Are you certain that the rest of your system can operate with SELinux enabled?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes it can. `uname -a`: `Linux vps-610.*****.com 2.6.18-028stab069.6 #1 SMP Wed May 26 18:10:06 MSD 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The kernel you are using was built without SELinux support. Using a stock kernel will not include the appropriate parts for your VPS. Rebuilding the kernel with SELinux support will cause the VPS parts to not work. You cannot use SELinux on your VPS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! anyway to configure `ftp_home_dir` of vsftpd without `setsebool` ?

Comment: @CanGeliş: If SELinux is disabled, there's no need to play with its booleans in order to allow programs to act. You can ignore that bit.

Comment: I did it with different way. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10):

Your VPS runs on OpenVZ, a container based "virtualization" which has no support for SELinux. If you need SELinux, you will need to switch to another hypervisor which supports SELinux in guests, such as Hyper-V, VMware, KVM, Xen, and possibly others.